# Qextserialport breaks my xml

Tags: qt, xml-parsing, qextserialport

I am trying to rewrite in c++ an application written in python.

All it does is to open a serial port and read some xml. In python i was using pyserial to read the xml and beautifulsoup to retrieve information. The output was like this.

```
<file><property>xx32</property></file>
```

Now i am using qextserialport to read from the serial port and the xml i get is something like this.

```
<
fil
e>
<prope
rty>xx32
</prop
erty>
</
file>
```

My problem is that i cant parse an xml like this. I get errors.

EDIT:

---

Qextserialport reads data from the serial port in set of bytes that are not fixed.
So how do i concatenate my xml into one string? I get an xml string every 4-5 seconds from the serial port.

here is my code

```
this->port = new QextSerialPort(com_port,QextSerialPort::EventDriven);
port->setBaudRate(BAUD57600);
port->setFlowControl(FLOW_OFF);
port->setParity(PAR_NONE);
port->setDataBits(DATA_8);
port->setStopBits(STOP_1);
port->setTimeout(0);

if (port->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly) == true)
{
    //qDebug()<< "hello";
    connect(port,SIGNAL(readyRead()),this,SLOT(onReadyRead()));
}
```

and the function that actually reads from the serial port

```
void CurrentCost::onReadyRead()
{
    QByteArray bytes;
    bytes = port->readAll();

    //qDebug() << "bytes read:" << bytes.size();
    //qDebug() << "bytes:" << bytes;
    ui->textBrowser->append(bytes);

}
```

Comment: Please post the code you use to reconstruct the XML.

Comment: Well this might be the problem. Do i have to reconstruct it?

Comment: post code you use to read from QextSerialPort. Maybe you add there unwanted '/n' symbols

Comment: well... append adding data to StringList, which causing that wrong new lines... try append data to QBytearray instead

Comment: `bytes read: 6 
bytes: "xx3452" 
bytes read: 5 
bytes: "</fil" 
bytes read: 3 
bytes: "e/>"` debug gives these values so it reads only part of the xml string at a time. If i append to QBytearray then it would be impossible to handle the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mean something like this:

```
class CurrentCost...{

private:
    QByteArray xmlData;
private slots:
   void onReadyRead();

};

void CurrentCost::onReadyRead()
{
    xmlData.append(port->readAll());

    if(xmlData.endsWith(/*what your port sending then xml is over&*/))
    {
        ui->textBrowser->append(xmlData);
        xmlData.clear();
    }

}
```

Comment: Nice! i didn't i didn't knew about endsWith.